# How to keep Lookup values when cloning a list?

Tags: list, workflow, 2016, lookup-column, site-collection

We have SharePoint 2016 and like to create some central maintained lists (a country list, flags, locations of our company, contacts etc.).

Since we have a workflow that clones a list to a different Site Collection, it was my idea to delete the list on the target Site Collection (by workflow) and then just copy it, if something changes on the source Site Collection.

The problem seems to be, that lookup values are referenced via list GUID, so other lists who used that cloned list will fail, since the list GUID is different.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

if you switch from using workflows to deploy your lists to for example [PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) you should be able to keep a [central template](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/sharepoint/create-list-library-pnp.html) using PnP Templates. That should be able to maintain your lookups and update fields accordingly. if that's not enough you can even write c# code using [Extensibility Providers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228121/how-to-provision-a-list-with-data-using-sharepoint-online-pnp-c)

if for whatever reason you have to keep workflows, how about a [custom workflow action](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13604.sharepoint-2010-create-a-workflow-activity-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx) to update your fields references with code?

Comment: Unfortunately we have strong restrictions at the farm. The workflow solution we use (ShareFlex) is the only option for server side code.